# Server block not routing correctly #nginxhelp

Tags: nginx, nginx-location, nginx-config

I have setup an NGINX server with multiple server blocks. I have configured 2 simple websites to run on the same server. They point to two different root paths specified in the respective server block file.

I have updated the DNS details for both the domains:

Name Servers: updated details as per registrar

A records: updated same static IP address

However, when I test with domain2.com  in the browser, it redirects to domain1.com. What am I doing wrong? I have already restarted the nginx server using:

```
sudo systemctl restart nginx
```

This is how my server block looks like:

```
# Default server configuration
#
server {

    root /var/www/domain1.com/html;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name domain1.com www.domain1.com;

    location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        # try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args; 
    }

    # pass PHP scripts to FastCGI server
    #
    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    #
    #   # With php-fpm (or other unix sockets):
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
    #   # With php-cgi (or other tcp sockets):
    #   fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    }

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    #location ~ /\.ht {
    #   deny all;
    #}

    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain1.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain1.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot


}

server {
    if ($host = www.domain1.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    if ($host = domain1.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name domain1.com www.domain1.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot

}
```

This is my second server block file:

```
# Default server configuration
#
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

    root /var/www/domain2.com/html;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name domain2.com www.domain2.com;

    location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        # try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args; 
    }

    # pass PHP scripts to FastCGI server
    #
    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    #
    #   # With php-fpm (or other unix sockets):
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
    #   # With php-cgi (or other tcp sockets):
    #   fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    }

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    #location ~ /\.ht {
    #   deny all;
    #}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your server block configuration files are perfect. Do not change anything. Let me explain what is happening. Your server block indicates that you installed certbot, probably for deploying Lets Encrypt SSL certificates for domain1.com whereas the server block for domain2.com does not have any entry managed by certbot yet. This probably means that you are using ssl certificates for domain1.com but not for domain2.com.

At the time of configuring SSL certificates for domain1.com, you probably selected the option of redirecting all traffic to SSL. Whats happening is that when the dns servers send a request for domain2.com to your web server, it expects an SSL certificate for that domain but finds none. It then redirects all traffic to the existing domain which has a valid SSL certificate installed.

However, the domain name on the certificate (domain1.com) shall not match the information passed on by the DNS server for domain2.com. Hence, it shall, in all likelihood, throw an error or warning message regarding invalid SSL certificates.

**Solution:** Install a new SSL certificate for domain2.com just like you did for domain1.com and everything should work fine.

Let me know if it works.

Comment: Just tested it and it works. That was perfect. The solution was so easy but nobody explained it the way you did. Thanks a lot.